# Firebase database doesn't show me the picture

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

So I am saving a picture to my database in the App, when I upload a picture. It uploads it correclty to the Storage and the Database, but it doesn't shows me it, when i restart the App.
I choose the file with the method filechooser() and upload it with fileuploader(). It works perfectly fine.[image: Picture should show up over the name]

```
enter code herepublic class ProfilBearbeiten extends AppCompatActivity  {




Button bestätigen;
private SharedPreferences speicher;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
TextView fullName,email;
EditText ort,beschreibung, telefonummer, interessen;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
String userId;
ImageView user;
Uri imageurl;
StorageReference mStorageRef;

private StorageTask uploadtask;
private Bitmap compressor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profilbearbeiten);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mStorageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Images");
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();

    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    fullName = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    email    = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    bestätigen = findViewById(R.id.btbestätigen);
    ort = findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    telefonummer = findViewById(R.id.tvTel);
    interessen = findViewById(R.id.tvInt);
    beschreibung = findViewById(R.id.tvBesc);
    user = findViewById(R.id.User);


    user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    filechooser();
                              //      fileuploader();

                                    Picasso.get().load(imageurl).into(user);


                                }
                            });


            bestätigen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // get Information from Edit Text or fileuploader()
                    final String eemail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    final String efullname = fullName.getText().toString();
                    final String eort = ort.getText().toString();
                    final String einteresssen = interessen.getText().toString();
                    final String ebeschreibung = beschreibung.getText().toString();
                    final String etelefonnummer = telefonummer.getText().toString();
                    final String bild = "";
                    final String image = imageurl != null ? imageurl.toString() : null;


                    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

                    //save edited Information in Database

                        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                        user.put("Benutername", efullname);
                        user.put("EMail", eemail);
                        user.put("Ort", eort);
                        user.put("Interessen", einteresssen);
                        user.put("Beschreibung", ebeschreibung);
                        user.put("Telefonnummer", etelefonnummer);
                        user.put("Image", image);
                        documentReference.set(user);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfilBearbeiten.this, Profile.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    fileuploader();
                }
            });
    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Benutername"));
            email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("EMail"));
            ort.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Ort"));
            telefonummer.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Telefonnummer"));
            interessen.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Interessen"));
            beschreibung.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Beschreibung"));
            Picasso.get().load(documentSnapshot.getString("Image")).into(user);


        }
    });





}
// uploads and open gallery on device
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode== 1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
        imageurl=data.getData();
        user.setImageURI(imageurl);

    }
}

private void filechooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


}

private String getExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
}


private void fileuploader () {
        StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+","+getExtension(imageurl));
        uploadtask = Ref.putFile(imageurl)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                    Toast.makeText(ProfilBearbeiten.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

}

So as you can see. The URL is saved under Images in the Database. When I upload the image and I switch through the other pages, the image is going to be shown, when i come back to this slide. But whenever i close the app and restart it ´, the picture disapears even though the URL is still in the database the same way. Maybe my mistake is how load it? `Picasso.get().load(documentSnapshot.getString("Image")).into(user);`

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are storing in the database is the local URL to the image on the device that uploads it to Cloud Storage. It is a local path on that specific Android device, where the camera wrote the file.

While this URL will initially work on that specific device, it may not work later (as the file may get cleaned up by Android), and it definitely won't work on other devices (since the image doesn't exist there).

To have a URL that will work anywhere and at any time, you'll want to generate a so-called download URL, and store *that* value in the database. You typically do this right after uploading the image, with a call to `getDownloadURL`:

```
StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+","+getExtension(imageurl));
uploadtask = Ref.putFile(imageurl)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfilBearbeiten.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
            Ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    // Got the download URL, so write it to the database
                    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

                    documentReference.update("Image", uri.toString());
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Also see the documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), which also shows how to prevent the nested task failure handlers.